# odoo 11 won't install properly

Tags: odoo-11

I just uninstalled odoo (openerp) and on reinstalling postgresql database won't install and it shows a server error (and won't start) after installing just the server.
[image]

How can I proceed from here.

I have checked in regedit (SOFTWARES) and can't find postgreSQL and I just can't understand what to do now.

**Added:**
On the web browser I get this [image]

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Install postgres manually, Refer this link for download copy of postgres https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `PostgreSQL` user before reinstalling `Odoo`.
Open `CMD` as `Administrator` and type:

```
net user openpgsvc /delete
```

Comment: Just did so but still, the problem (first picture) did come up again. Please any other solution or referal and I will be on it straight away.

Comment: Run this after you remove complitly odoo and postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue. Sorted it by deleting Postgres under regedit HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE --Software ---Postgres folders